# How does the EU enforce its media ban against Russia Today?

Tags: european-union, media

> Brussels — The European Union's chief executive says the 27-nation
> bloc will close its airspace to Russian airlines, fund supplies of
> weapons to Ukraine and ban some pro-Kremlin media outlets in response
> to Russia's invasion.
>
> European Commission President Ursula von der Leyen said Sunday that
> "for the first time ever, the European Union will finance the purchase
> and delivery of weapons and other equipment to a country that is under
> attack."
>
> Von der Leyen added that "we are shutting down the EU airspace for
> Russians. We are proposing a prohibition on all Russian-owned, Russian
> registered or Russian-controlled aircraft. These aircraft will no more
> be able to land in, take off or overfly the territory of the EU."

https://www.cbsnews.com/news/ukraine-russia-european-union-airspace-rt-sputnik/

How does the EU enforce its media ban against Russia Today? Is there some kind of punishment meted out against countries that decide to not ban it or to not do enough to make it inaccessible to be consumed by the public?

Comment: It doesn't look like any country didn't follow the ruling. Even Hungary reportedly followed it. https://hungarytoday.hu/hungary-russia-today-sputnik-suspension-broadcast/ I doubt there's a specific mechanism aside from the usus non-compliance ones at EU level.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73703/how-do-western-democracies-justify-censorship-of-foreign-media-outlets